# Weak solution of a heat equation is zero?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

I work on a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $u \in H^1(0,T;H^{-1})\cap L^2(0,T;H^1)$ be a solution of the heat equation:
$$\langle u', v \rangle + \int \nabla u \nabla v = 0$$
for each test function $v$. The solution has the property 
$$\int_\Omega u(t) = 0$$
for each $t$.

Is it possible to conclude from this information that $u \equiv 0$?

Comment: This might be more appropriate at [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/). For an answer, what about unit ball as $\Omega$ and $u(x,t)=x_1$? This solves the heat equation and averages to zero. You specified no boundary conditions.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think use of $H^{-1}$ as a function space in the formulation of the question means that the boundary condition, which isn't written is Dirichlet $0$ (but it doesn't change the answer to the question asked).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is 'no' since the function $e^{-t}\sin (x)$ solves the heat equation on $\Omega=(-1,1)\times \mathbb R_+$ but the integral is zero by symmetry. If you want an example where $n>1$, just add a dummy variable.